# COUNTIFS by multiple greater than criteria in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to use `COUNT()OVER(ORDER BY)` in SQL to create the `COUNT` column below. Here, COUNT gives you the number of tickets sold equal or over the current row price from the purchase date until  the event date.  In this case the vent happened on `1/15/13`.  For example, from `12/3/2012 to 1/15/13` we sold 5 tickets at or above $420.  Another example f, from `12/25/12 to 1/15/13` we sold 6 tickets at or above.

In Excel the formula would be `=+COUNTIFS([Price],">="&[@Price],[Date],">="&[@Date])`. This is how the `COUNT` column is calculated.

In SQL the furthest I have gotten is below and the result is in the SQL_COUNT column. As you can see it does not work.

```
SELECT DATE, PRICE, 
COUNT(PRICE) OVER (order by PRICE desc)
FROM O.ELEMENTS ELEMENTS
WHERE (DATE={ts '2013-01-15 00:00:00'})
ORDER BY PRICE DESC


PRICE   DATE        COUNT   SQL_COUNT
700 1/8/2013    2   2
700 1/10/2013   1   2
440 1/9/2013    2   3
420 12/3/2012   5   5
420 12/18/2012  4   5
400 12/11/2012  5   6
390 12/3/2012   7   7
370 8/29/2012   11  11
370 11/29/2012  10  11
370 11/29/2012  10  11
370 12/17/2012  5   11
360 10/18/2012  11  12
350 1/5/2013    5   14
350 1/9/2013    3   14
340 6/23/2012   20  20
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what version?

Comment: The data is incomplete.  You have counts of 20 but only have 15 data rows.

Comment: True, this is only a sample of the total rows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do this with the window functions.  You can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select date, price,
       (select count(*) from o.elements e2 where e2.date >= e.date and e2.price >= e.price
       ) as YourCount
from o.elements e
WHERE (DATE={ts '2013-01-15 00:00:00'})
ORDER BY PRICE DESC
```

This problem has bothered me all day (which has fortunately been a light day at work).  I am increasingly thinking that this problem cannot be solved with the window functions alone -- which surprises me.  The window functions treat each dimension independently.  In other words, the `order by` clause goes through everything in one dimension before considering the next.

Consider this geometrically.  The two axes are the price and date dimensions.  The data is actually a scatter plot along these two dimensions.  A given point breaks the scatter plot into four quadrants.  What we are looking for is the number of points in D (where both price and date are larger):

```
|  C   |  D
|------+------
|      |
|  A   |  B
 -------------
```

By the way, the geometric problem is essentially the same, when using the ranks of the variable values rather than the actual values.

We can readily get the count of records in any two adjacent regions.  For instance, C+D is:

```
count(*) over (order by price)
```

Or, for A+B:

```
count(*) over (order by price desc)
```

The problem is mixing the dimensions.  These are vertical lines that break the space into two distinct regions.  There is no way to combine them in an expression that captures just "D".  We could get something like A-C by subtracting two values, but that still doesn't help.

This doesn't *prove* that the original goal is impossible.  It is merely suggestive that using sorts on one dimension does not suffice.

Adding a second dimension `order by price, date` also doesn't work.  If there are no ties on price, this does nothing and we are back to initial case.  A trick like taking the ranking by price and the ranking by date and using the sum (or average) doesn't work.  The resulting geometric interpretation has lines at 45-degrees, which is not what we want.

As far as I can tell, some form of self-join is the only solution.  The form in my original answer (at the top) is probably the simplest way to do this.  If you have an index on price and date, should even be efficient.

Comment: Genius!!! Now, the database has multiple event dates and each event date has somewhat similar Price and Date data. (i.e. there is an Event_Date column) How do I partition query so that I get the same "reverse running" total by Event_Date.

Comment: Can you ask another question with sample data for it?  I am still pondering whether this is possible using analytic functions.  I think I understand why it is not possible, but I don't understand well enough to explain it (meaning there is a good chance I'm wrong).

Comment: Is there a reason why my alias disappear when I run this query through MS Query?